# how to fetch array object elements in php within an array

Tags: php, arrays, var

I am going through a php script which has something like this

```
echo "<pre>";
var_export($someObj->details);
echo "</pre>";
```

and the output is something like : http://pastebin.com/gEAFg6R4

now how do I fetch paricular lines for eg if I just want to fetch the height, if have vehicle or not and is male or female ? what is var_export($someObj->details); doing ?

Comment: ok let me put it straight. I am working with tera wurfl database. it has a sample php script which after inputing user agent gives output with following http://pastebin.com/hxJLEiEF . now i just want to fetch few informations from there. like mobile model. either it uses javascript or not etc. the output is from var_export($wurflObj->capabilities);
I hope this much info makes my question fair enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please study the PHP manual on arrays http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php - the third example shows how to access nested array contents.

In your case it would be:

```
print $someObj->details["city"];

print $someObj->details["details"]["have_vehicle"];
```

Can't tell for the rest, as your output paste is incomplete.

Comment: thanks for the manual link. btw i have commented new link with full output. and now going through the manual. hope i will be able to figure out :D

Comment: thank you very much for the manual and the answer too :) I now can myself figure out how to fetch :) \m/ \m/

Comment: Okay cool. Also test out `print_r` in place of `var_dump` - I find that it's sometimes more readable for finding the right array tree.